# Database migration issue in gitlab after upgrading gitlab

Tags: gitlab, upgrade, database-migration

Recently i have upgraded gitlab after which few database migrations are not yet migrated and are showing status as down.

We have tried sudo gitlab-rake db:migrate but still some migration are failing.

```
== 20200213224220 AddSprints: migrating =======================================
-- create_table(:sprints, {:id=>:bigserial})
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::ReadOnlySqlTransaction: ERROR:  cannot execute CREATE TABLE in a read-only transaction
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/migrate/20200213224220_add_sprints.rb:7:in `change'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ReadOnlySqlTransaction: ERROR:  cannot execute CREATE TABLE in a read-only transaction
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/migrate/20200213224220_add_sprints.rb:7:in `change'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo touch /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/db/migrate/*
```

or

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/
```

and run migration again.